# How to get process 'Max' memory usage for each method process

Tags: .net

How to get process 'Max' memory usage for each method process

---

Like visual stuido debug diagnostic tools, can know `max memory uasage` by chart
[image]

I've tried [dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) `MemoryDiagnoser` to get `Allocated`, but it's `all memory usage` not max memory usage.

```
    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    public class BenchmarkBase
    {
    
    }
```

Why I'd like to do it?
Because I want to make sure that the maximum memory usage does not cause OOM